# Can I develop libgdx game with C#?

Tags: c#, libgdx

I see some articles through Google that I can use `libgdx` in C#. Is it true? I found no official and unonfficial about this. If there is a way, please tell me how. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick googling seems to suggest they are using IKVM, which is a JVM that runs on top of .NET. It is not official, and "you can use libgdx with C#" is about as true as "you can use any Java library with C#." In fact, it looks like the ios backend is build on top of MonoTouch, so the compatibility should be reasonably well-tested, although I still can't find .NET binaries in the official release. However, I imagine C#+libgdx would not be compatibile with the HTML5 or Android backends.